# Problema ao enviar aplicação para o hostgator com o codeingniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Fui enviar um sistema de `pdv` para minha hospedagem HostGator ai deu o seguinte erro:

> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/basic340/public_html/placeexpress.com.br/core/core/Exceptions.php:170)
>
> Filename: helpers/url_helper.php
>
> Line Number: 546

essa é a linha do código.

```
default         : header("Location: ".$uri, TRUE, $http_response_code);
```

Comment: esse sistema foi feito por você? normalmente isso acontece quando você tenta enviar alguma informação depois que o servidor já enviou o header. por exemplo enviar cookies.

Comment: no localhost funciona normal ai fui enviar para o hostgator não funcionou

Comment: Será que não é o debug ativado que manda uma saída de texto? precisa verificar se é isso e a linha de código que o erro indica.

Comment: Geralmente esse erro acontece devido a outro erro anterior.